# ASP.NET WebHost to Host migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm trying to migrate my application startup from `WebHost` based to (newer/recommended) `Host`.

When I change:

```
private static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
            loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration));

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

    // start the app.
    host.Run();
}
```

to:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })            // Add Serilog Logger
        .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
            loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration));

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

    // start the app.
    host.Run();
}
```

I'm getting the following error related to dependency injection:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Localization.IStringLocalizer Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: UniLocalizer.UniLocalizer': No constructor for type 'UniLocalizer.UniLocalizer' can be instantiated using services from the service container and default values.)'

GPT gives me clues that some services which may be initialized in `WebHost` are not default for `Host` (which by design should be lighter) and those services may be requested by [UniLocalizer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UniLocalizer).

Do have any idea how diagnose / fix this issue?

(for WebHost application works fine)

Comment: Are you sure the method to configure services in your Startup class is being invoked?

Comment: Can you please post a full [mre]? For example @github?

Comment: Not sure if I can reproduce minimal example - project is quite big. I will check if I could extract parts that are involved.

Comment: @digital_jedi in Host version services are configured in Startup.cs. I have also tried version without Startup.cs (plain Program.js with top-level statements) error is still the same.

Comment: @GuruStron I have updated Unilocalizer.Demo project and issue can be reproduced there. Here the repo: https://github.com/it-xtech-dev/UniLocalizer

Comment: The first thing to do when you get an exception is to read its message carefully. In your case the exception message boils down to _"No constructor for type `UniLocalizer.UniLocalizer` can be instantiated using services from the service container and default values."_ You should look at your service `UniLocalizer` and notice that it has one public constructor requiring another service and `string` resource location. `string` values will not be injected by DI by default and that's the cause of exception. You have a factory that handles it, to fix this - remove adding `UniLocalizer` to services.

Comment: Also, this question would be answered quicker by others if you would have post a minimal reproducible example including the code for `UniLocalizer` and pieces responsible for registering it within service collection. Something to keep in mind for the future.

Comment: @Prolog Thank you for elaboration. Do you know whats the difference between WebHost and Host in this context? App starts ups fine with WebHost.

Comment: [What is the difference between Host and WebHost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59745401/what-is-the-difference-between-host-and-webhost-class-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: @Prolog thanks for your engagement. I'm applying changes and review UniLocalizer code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the code in repository, the issue is related to configuring `UniLocalizer` for dependency injection. The class has no parameterless constructor, and its dependencies `IStorageProvider` and `string` (and optionally `CultureInfo`) cannot be resolved from the container because they have not been configured for injection.

However, it appears that the `UniLocalizer` class does not even *need* to be injected, because no classes in your solution are injecting it. Rather, it is the `UniLocalizerFactory` which is injected and responsible for instantiating `UniLocalizer` instances.

Two ways to fix this:

1. Remove the configuration of `UniLocalizer` for dependency injection, from lines 57 and 58 of your `UniLocalizer.ServiceExtensions` class. This configuration feels unnecessary, given the usage of the factory class.
2. Another option (not recommended) is to make `UniLocalizer` injectable, either by adding a parameterless constructor to `UniLocalizer` (example: `public UniLocalizer() { }`), or by configuring its dependencies for dynamic injection with a factory method delegate. This feels useless to me, as no classes are injecting `UniLocalizer` directly, it entirely defeats the purpose of your factory pattern!

Comment: Thanks very much for your review and answer. I'm about to refactor UniLocalizer.